# How to save a checkbox to a userform which was created programmatically in vba-excel

Tags: excel, vba

I created a checkbox for an existing userform in excel via an active X command button which i programmed to keep record of databases of info, however soon after the checkbox disappears on adding another set of information as well as the checkbox-name does not even appear.

```
Sub Checkbox()
Dim chkBox As Control


Set chkBox = Te.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox" & Range("D3").Value)
End Sub
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

End Sub

Comment: What code runs when you add another set of information?

Comment: Are you not positioning the checkbox?  You haven't really given us much information here.

Comment: I haven't done the positioning as yet that's no problem